# Send data to REST service from java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, put

I have implemented REST service in C# to upload an image :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "add/{idAlbum}/{name}/image")]
void Add(string idAlbum, string name, Stream image);
```

I have succeeded to use it with a C# client :

```
byte[] image = lireFichier(@"C:\Users\user\Pictures\asap2.jpeg");
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
var results = client.UploadData("http://localhost:1767/ImageService.svc/add/1/REST/image", "PUT", image);
```

So now I want to use it with a java client (android) like this (Not work) :

```
HttpURLConnection conn = ( HttpURLConnection ) new URL( "http://localhost:1767/ImageService.svc/add/1/RESTjava/image" ).openConnection();  

conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");

conn.setDoOutput( true );
conn.connect(); 

OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();  

Bitmap img = ((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.entourage)).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
byte[] data = bao.toByteArray();
out.write(data);
```

I haven't any error but this didn't work. No Exceptions.

```
 06-05 14:11:57.736: I/ASAP PICS(746): onPreExecute
 06-05 14:11:57.745: I/ASAP PICS(746): doInBackground
 06-05 14:11:57.816: I/System.out(746): 405
 06-05 14:44:26.245: D/dalvikvm(971): GC freed 238 objects / 332400 bytes in 34ms
 06-05 14:11:57.905: I/ASAP PICS(746): onPostExecute
```

Comment: Exceptions? Return code?

Comment: No Exceptions.06-05 14:11:57.736: I/ASAP PICS(746): onPreExecute
06-05 14:11:57.745: I/ASAP PICS(746): doInBackground
06-05 14:11:57.816: I/System.out(746): 405
06-05 14:11:57.905: I/ASAP PICS(746): onPostExecute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution !

First I put the REST service in POST method :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "add/{idAlbum}/{name}")]
void Add(string idAlbum, string name, Stream image);
```

And finally the java client :

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:1767/ImageService.svc/add/1/RESTjava");

Bitmap img = ((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.entourage)).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
byte[] data = bao.toByteArray();

ByteArrayEntity bimg = new ByteArrayEntity(data);
post.setEntity(bimg);
new DefaultHttpClient().execute(post);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do `flush` on your `OutputStream`: `out.flush();`. This is the answer.

Comment: @user2455427 Add also `out.close();`

Comment: Don't work but I have one more message in the logcat : 
06-05 14:13:15.415: D/dalvikvm(809): GC freed 1128 objects / 72032 bytes in 44ms

Answer (score 0):

> I/System.out(746): 405

HTTP 405 = Method not allowed.

I guess you have to add authentication?

Comment: I think it's normal because I see this message when I go at url with a browser. But it's work with the C# client.

Comment: Then you'll have to check out what the C# client is doing differently :) I bet there is some kind of Authentication involved.